# Selenium and Pyvirutaldisplay not working together on Mac

Tags: python, linux, macos, selenium-webdriver

I've been using Selenium in conjunction with the python pyvirutaldisplay library on Linux to have the webdriver run entirely in the virtual display window. However the code doesn't behave as expected when used on a Mac machine. The basic case is as follows:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from pyvirutaldisplay import Display

d = Display()
d.start()
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
```

What happens on Linux, and what I expect to happen is that a virtual display is opened and then the webdriver is applied to it. However what happens on Mac is that the virtual display is created and then the webdriver is launched but not applied to the virtual display.

I really don't know why this is happening. I'm not sure if it's because Mac GUI applications behave differently than on Linux so pyvirutaldisplay setting the "DISPLAY" environment variable and starting a Xvfb server isn't enough to apply the webdriver to the new display. I don't know and any help would be appreciated.

If it helps the Mac in question is on OS: Ventura 13.5.2. Selenium version is: 4.4.2. Browser is Chromedriver 117.0.5938.88. I also have xquartz installed on the Mac and Xvfb added to the PATH.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to run a headless test on a Mac, you could use the new headless mode (`--headless=new`), which works the same as regular headed Chrome:

```py
from selenium import webdriver

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("--headless=new")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
```

On websites, the only noticeable difference between that and headed Chrome is the user agent. If keeping that the same is important to you, modify the user agent by replacing `HeadlessChrome` with just `Chrome`.

---

Also, as an alternative to `pyvirtualdisplay`, you might be able to use [sbvirtualdisplay](https://pypi.org/project/sbvirtualdisplay/), which is specifically designed for Selenium running virtually. It's used by popular Selenium frameworks, such as https://github.com/seleniumbase/SeleniumBase

Example usage:

```py
from sbvirtualdisplay import Display

display = Display(visible=0, size=(1440, 1880))
display.start()

# Run browser tests in a headless environment

display.stop()
```

That also includes a context manager format:

```py
from sbvirtualdisplay import Display

with Display(visible=0, size=(1440, 1880)):
    # Run browser tests in a headless environment
    ...
```

Comment: Unfortunately I do need the webdriver to be headed, because I need to take a full screenshot of the entire webdriver GUI, not just what selenium can capture.  A bit unusual but it's my use case.

I didn't know about this library though I'll check it out and see if it could help thanks!